# Can every element of a homotopy group of a smooth manifold be represented by an immersion?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory, spheres

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$. Let $\alpha \in \pi_i (M)$, for some $i \leq n$, and $f:S^i \to M$ be a map of the sphere representing the homotopy class $\alpha$. Can $f$ always be chosen to be an immersion? I.e. does every homotopy class of the maps from the sphere $S^i$ to $M$ contain an immersion?

This feels like it should be a classical result but I don't know much about this, nor do I have any idea how to approach such a problem. If it is true, could I get a reference to the result, or if it's simple, a hint for the solution? Or is there some subtlety that I'm missing that makes this statement false?

Comment: Certainly not in general when $i=n$.  Then an immersion is covering map.  I don't know what happens for, say $i=n-1$.

Comment: On the other side, for  sufficiently large codimension ($i\le\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ I believe) such an immersion exists by approximation/transversality arguments.

Comment: Asked and answered on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375919/can-every-element-of-a-homotopy-group-of-a-smooth-manifold-be-represented-by-an